# Using Armadillo library; Linking Error with BLAS and LAPACK

Tags: visual-c++, linker, lapack, blas, armadillo

I am trying to compile and run the sample in example2.cpp from Armadillo, using the pre-compiled blas and lapack dll files provided. This is what I didin Visual C++ 2013:

1) I set up a new and empty win32 console application project;

2) Add a new and empty cpp file called test.cpp.

3) I copyed the content of example2.cpp into this test.cpp file.

4) In the project properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories, I added the path of the "include" folder from the Armadillo library.

5) In project properties->linker->General->Additional Library Directories, I added the path
of the folder in which the pre-compiled blas and lapack dlls are lacating (the corresponding lib files are in the same folder);

6) In project properties->linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, I added the lib files for the pre-compiled blas and lapack dlls, i.e. blas_win64_MT.lib and lapack_win64_MT.lib.

Then I compile the whole project, and still got a lot of LNK2019 error, indicating there are unresolved symbols when referring to blas and lapack routines.

Can someone help me to figure out what is going on here?

Comment: If you check Configuration Manager, are you compiling for x64? Just guessing from the names of the libraries you're linking in, they may be compiled for x64, and if you're building for x86, that's possibly the source of your problem.

Comment: `win32` won't work, as the LAPACK and BLAS libraries supplied with Armadillo are 64 bit.

Comment: Hi Colin and Mtall, thank you very much for your advice. That indeed worked after I changed the project configuration to x64 (previously I thought it should be set as default on a 64bit os...). One more question, though, because I am truely a newby on dll stuff: the program runs smoothly when I put the dlls in the project folder. Is there another way to do this? In other words is it possible to put the dlls on a common folder so that many other projects can refer to them? How should I set configure the project in order to achieve this?Thank you very much.

Comment: There are various solutions, but to be honest, handling of DLLs (or more precisely, shared libraries) by Windows is not the greatest. If you're going to be doing a lot of numerical work or simulations, you may wish to explore using other operating systems.