# Armadillo C++ linking

Tags: armadillo

Newbie programmer:
I wanted to use Armadillo C++ Linear Algebra library and have issues installing it. 
The instructions as provided by developers of the library are as follow:

## 8: Windows: Installation

The installation is comprised of 3 steps:

- Step 1:
  Copy the entire "include" folder to a convenient location
  and tell your compiler to use that location for header files
  (in addition to the locations it uses already).
  Alternatively, you can use the "include" folder directly.
- Step 2:
  Modify "include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp" to indicate which
  libraries are currently available on your system. For example,
  if you have LAPACK, BLAS (or OpenBLAS), ARPACK and SuperLU present,
  uncomment the following lines:

  ```
  #define ARMA_USE_LAPACK
  #define ARMA_USE_BLAS
  #define ARMA_USE_ARPACK
  #define ARMA_USE_SUPERLU
  ```

  If you don't need sparse matrices, don't worry about ARPACK or SuperLU.
- Step 3:
  Configure your compiler to link with LAPACK and BLAS
  (and optionally ARPACK and SuperLU).

I have no idea how to install it. Im using MS Visual Studio 2015.
Please help.

Comment: Try all the steps in this question and the hints in the comments, then it should run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232219/using-armadillo-library-linking-error-with-blas-and-lapack

Comment: got it! Thanks a ton..